# Find and Replace in a csv file Perl

Tags: perl, csv, replace

I've been working through examples on find and replace for a CSV file but I can't seem to get anything to work and I am hoping for some help. Running this on windows.

I have to deal with a poorly-formatted CSV file where commas and double-quotes are all in the wrong place.

Sample CSV:

```
Device,Block,Block,Block
Value,Power,Current(Best", Set," Ex),Power
Data, 3, 4, 3
```

I want to replace `'", '` to `'_'` before processing. The goal being that `Current(Best_Set_Ex)` will be in one column.

Perl script (updated): sanitize.pl

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    s/," /_/g;
    s/", /_/g;
    print ;
}
```

Command:

```
perl -p -i.orig sanitize.pl perltest.csv
```

Error: Can't open perl script "orig": No such file or directory

Comment: You should write a Perl *program* instead of trying to do the whole thing on one command line. You will get much better diagnostic messages that way.

Comment: Apologize, it has been edited. I am running this as a script, now as a  one line command

Comment: I am switching to using powershell script that will suffice.
`[io.file]::readalltext("p:\pstest.csv").replace('", ',"_") | Out-File "P:\psreplaced.csv" -enconding ascii -force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Unix box to hand to check, but the first thing I notice about

```
perl -p -i.backup -e 's/", /_/g' .\perltest.csv
```

is that you are misunderstanding the `-i` switch.

You probably want either a bare `-i` if you are brave (it will modify the file in-place without a backup) or something like `-i.back` which will preserve the contents of the original file with `.back` appended to the name.

The rest should work fine.

Comment: If I run `-i.back` it says it can't open perl script ".back": No such file

Comment: `perl -i.back -pe 's/", /_/g' perltest.csv`

Comment: Appreciate it! Any ideas on my -i.back will say Can't open perl script ".back" ??

Comment: It works fine as I have shown it. Please show the command line you are using to get this effect.

Comment: `perl -i.back -pe 's/", /_/g' perltest.csv` returns "Can't open perl script ".back": No such file or directory"

Comment: @snoop: Then something is very wrong with your installation and I can't imagine what. Are you *absolutely sure* you're not putting a space after the `-i`? I assume you're on a Linux system? What does `which perl` give you?

Comment: I'm on windows 7 with strawberry perl 5.18.2 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread. Same response with `-i.back` and `-i .back`

Comment: Then the quotes for the `-e` option need to be double ones, like this `perl -i.back -pe "s/\", /_/g" perltest.csv` but that doesn't explain it trying to execute the `-i` option as a program. How are you entering this command line? Are you using `cmd.exe` as your command shell?

Comment: I'm actually running it from powershell

Comment: Ah, well don't. And please say that you're using PowerShell (and Windows) if you post any other questions. Just click Start and type `cmd` and enter. Run perl from there.

Comment: Ugh, yeah it works perfectly in cmd. Thanks for your help & patience. I should have specified

Answer (score 0):

I would write a script (as @Borodin suggested in comment). In first instance just write revised text to STDOUT

```
    use warnings;
    use strict;

    while (<>) {
        s/," /_/g;
        s/", /_/g;
        print ;
    }
```

When you are happy it works

```
    perl -i.bak sanatise_quotes.pl perltest.csv
```

From mention of powershell. I am assuming you are on Windows, in which case you need  double quotes`"` rather than single quotes `'`. It is interpreting the `\perltest.csv` as part of the `-e`

If you insist on a one liner, use following - but I dislike having to quote the `"` as `\"`.
Add `-i.bak` when you are happy it is working.

```
     perl -p  -e "s/,\" /_/g" perltest.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i can't get -i.orig to work. If I don't include the in place backup it won't let me run it either.

Answer (score 0):

I took Borodin & justintime's advice and went with a program instead of a one liner. Thank you guys for your input on this. I have not resolved why `-i.back` was giving me the Can't open perl file ".back".

Script:

```
use English;
sub inplace_sanitize {
my ( $filename, $pattern1, $pattern2, $replacement1 ) = @_;
    local @ARGV = ( $filename ),
    $INPLACE_EDIT = '.back';
while ( <> ) {
    s/\Q$pattern1/$replacement1/g;
    s/\Q$pattern2/$replacement1/g;
print;
}
}

$filename = 'perltest.csv';
$pattern1 = '", ';
$pattern2 = '," ';
$replacement1 = '_';

&inplace_sanitize($filename, $pattern1, $pattern2, $replacement1);
```

Comment: Please, *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` a the start of every Perl program; don't `use English`; always *indent your program properly*; don't assign to `@ARGV`, or at least not in public; don' try to do in-place edit on Windows - it's broken; and ***never*** call a subroutine with an ampersand `&`. Oh, and don't use PowerShell :)